# Error 500 after choosing additional payment method (onepage checkout) - magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, error, payment-methods, prototype-js

I have added additional payment method almost the same as banktransfer, and everything works fine until this payment is checked at checkout. This payment shows up in adminpanel and front end.

Html code in checkout form looks the same for both payment methods.

```
<dl class="sp-methods" id="checkout-payment-method-load">
    <dt id="dt_method_custom">
            <input id="p_method_custom" value="custom" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="Custom Payment" onclick="payment.switchMethod('custom')" class="radio validation-passed" autocomplete="off">
            <label for="p_method_custom">Custom Payment </label>
    </dt>
        <dd id="dd_method_custom">
            <ul class="form-list checkout-agreements" id="payment_form_custom">
        <li>
            <div class="przelew-instructions-content agreement-content">
               some text      </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

    </dd>
        <dt id="dt_method_banktransfer">
            <input id="p_method_banktransfer" value="banktransfer" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="Banktransfer title" onclick="payment.switchMethod('banktransfer')" class="radio validation-passed" autocomplete="off">
            <label for="p_method_banktransfer">Banktransfer title </label>
    </dt>
        <dd id="dd_method_banktransfer">
            <ul class="form-list checkout-agreements" id="payment_form_banktransfer" style="display:none;">
        <li>
            <div class="banktransfer-instructions-content agreement-content">some text </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </dd>

</dl>
```

Unfortunately after clicking next step, i got 500 error if i choose this custom method. I have found nothing in Apache log. Chrome log looks like this:

```
headerJSON    :    null
readyState    :    4
request    :    klass
responseJSON    :    null
responseText    :    ""
responseXML    :    null
status    :    500
statusText    :    "Internal Server Error"
transport    :    XMLHttpRequest
__proto__    :    Object
_getHeaderJSON    :    ()
_getResponseJSON    :    ()
constructor    :    klass()
getAllHeaders    :    ()
getAllResponseHeaders    :    ()
getHeader    :    (name)
getResponseHeader    :    (name)
getStatus    :    ()
getStatusText    :    ()
initialize    :    (request)
status    :     0
statusText    :    ""
__proto__    :    Object
```

Function payment.save() works, but next one makes error.

```
reloadStep: function(prevStep) {
        var updater = new Ajax.Updater(prevStep + '-progress-opcheckout', this.progressUrl, {
            method:'get',
           onFailure:this.ajaxFailure.bind(this),
            onComplete: function(response){
                this.checkout.resetPreviousSteps();
console.log(response);
            },
            parameters:prevStep ? { prevStep:prevStep } : null
        });
    },
```

Any idea what could I messed up?

///Bypassed
I've made a custom module for another payment method instead of duplicating method in core files. Now works fine, no problems in JS.
Any way, i'll try to check why the problem occured.

Comment: assuming you're using php-fpm you should check the fpm logs. I don't think there's any point putting display_errors on as it's an ajax request.